# Is it feasible to do recommendation with Parse and only iOS devices?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, social-networking

I am currently working on a social-networking based app on iOS. I try the online DB service and cloud service provider "Parse". But what i really do through this platform is just to retrieve data for the "users","messages" and "activities" in that DB. 
I want to implement the recommendation function into my app which requires some sort of logic after the retrieval of the data. Is it feasible to integrate some of this logic into the "Parse" platform and avoid setting up the server?

Comment: Please be more specific to your needs. Your question is extremely vague, and vague questions usually render vague answers. The shortest answer to your question is YES. but you have something in particular in mind, you should share that and any code you've already tried so we can help you in that particular instance

Comment: Thx for your advice i will keep that in mind. I would specify the question as clear as i can. I want to deploy some logic to do some filter on the database. Just like the servlet which does his own part of a web application, i want to implement some of that function to achieve the goal. Is it available?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking if you can have server side logic run on the Parse side?  Yes, you can and this is fairly standard practice in the Parse universe. You an use Cloud Code, which is Javascript run on the parse servers and you can link the scripts in to before you save objects, after you save objects, or just standalone functions.  Here are some details:

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide

Hope that helps!

Comment: sorry, you don't need cloud code to do what the OP is asking. You can do this all in-app. OP is simply asking after you retrieve data from the backend can you implement logic to do something with that data. It can be done yes, doesn't have to be cloud code, it's just a poorly written question - they should be more specific

Comment: For example, i have a database which stores the entity of "Activity". I want to do some filtering when the users query about the activities satisfying his interest. I have learned about jsp before and what i want is partially the function of servlet (receive a request containg some paremeters and then run some logic in order to response to that request)

Comment: Yes - you can do just that with cloud code. If you read through that cloud code guide, you will see you can pass it any parameters, or link in to any data lifecycle event on the server side and perform whatever logic you desire.  For simple filtering of queries, you may be better off filtering client side on the PFQuery, but that is your call - each case is different.